# Error from printf() function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MINUTES_IN_HOUR  60
int main() {
    // Two trains will pass each other at a certain time whne they are at an initial fixed distance apart.
    // When will they pass each other and how much distance did each train have to travel?
    // 1 corresponds to train 1, and 2 corresponds to train 2. 

    float distance_1_mile, distance_2_mile, distance_total_mile, rate_1_mph, rate_2_mph, time_minute;

    time_minute = (distance_total_mile * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) / (rate_1_mph + rate_2_mph);
    distance_1_mile = rate_1_mph * time_minute / MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
    distance_2_mile = rate_2_mph * time_minute / MINUTES_IN_HOUR;

    printf("The rate of train 1 and train 2 respectively are what values?\n");
    scanf("%f%f", &rate_1_mph, &rate_2_mph);

    printf("What was the total distance the trains were apart initially?\n");
    scanf("%f", &distance_total_mile);

    printf("The time it takes both trains to arrive side-by-side is %.3f minutes.\n", time_minute);

    printf("The distance train 1 had to travel was %.2f miles.\n",  distance_1_mile);
    printf("The distance train 2 had to travel was %.2f miles.\n", distance_2_mile);

    return 0;
}
```

The error I received was: `"warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int *"`.

I've tried looking this up on this site, and I saw the same question solved two different ways but neither seemed to work. I also didn't post the entire code because the other example I saw didn't either, and their question was answered.

Comment: You're passing a pointer to an integer, where you should pass a floating point value. You would need to convert one to the other.

Comment: Note that it appears your `distance*` variables are pointers instead of normal integers (judging from the warning message; without a variable declaration, we can't tell for sure). That doesn't make sense; make them normal integers instead (and then cast them to float).

Comment: Please consider posting the entire code. We don't know what are the types of `distance_1_mile` and `distance_2_mile`?

Comment: When you say %.31f you are saying that you want 31 digits to the right of the decimal point.  Like 0.0123456789012345678901234568890 -- that seems a might excessive.  You probably want %3.1f

Comment: also show declaration of `time_minute`

Answer (score -1):

The compiler is telling you what the problem is, I'm assuming that somewhere you have a line that looks like

```
int rate_1_mph, rate_2_mph, distance_total_mile, time_minute;
```

Change the int to float.

When you're done with this you need to change all every %d to %f within your printf statements.  %d is actually used for integers, not doubles.

Comment: The compiler error message indicates it is getting an `int *`, not an `int`. That's more problematic than just changing %d to %f.

Comment: Well I am getting a value now, though it is wrong. The 3rd scanf("%1f", &distance_total_mile") doesn't allow me to input a value.

Comment: I was able to get the third back by deleting the 1 from the %1f. Still getting an incorrect value for the time. I also am getting 0.00 for the distances traveled. I checked my math and I am able to get the correct answer.